# Transferring vector lines from QGIS to AutoCAD (offset "insertion point")

Tags: qgis, autocad

I have a set of parcel boundary and building footprint lines that I've isolated and saved as a dxf filetype within QGIS. However, when I import the dxf file into AutoCAD, the insertion point is annoyingly far from the origin point. I've put some photos below showing each step.

[image: File within QGIS]

[image: Export]

[image]

[image: Zoomed in on imported dxf file]

As you can see, the "insertion point" for the block is a vast distance away from the actual block, so I have to "bedit", "copybase", exit the block editor and paste into the model space at the origin point.

I've tried toying with scale, projection, and extent, all to no avail. Regarding the extent, it seems that QGIS is not responding according to my needs when I select "current layer extent". Perhaps there are features of the layer outside of the extent of the lines I need, but I'm unable to see if there are, so any suggestions on how to do that would be helpful.

Comment: I was going to suggest trying out exporting via Project > Export project as DXF rather than using the Save As feature (this additionally allows you to carry across layer styles). However it seems like the default behaviour is to make the base point 0,0 of whatever CRS the project is in, and obviously in most instances that will be a very long way from the actual features are. Because most GIS don't have the concept of a "block", insertion points are somewhat moot. Location is determined by a CRS not arbitrary coordinates. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Usually when I export dxfs from QGIS it's to overlay them on survey dwgs that use the same coordinates in CAD so I just insert the dxf without specifying an insertion point and it goes where it needs to. However when overlaying on architectural dwgs that use an arbitrary coordinate system, yeah, I've had to do the same thing as you and redefine insertion points so I can move things around easily. Perhaps ArcGIS or Microstation handle dwg block exports more like how they are expected to behave?

Comment: @she_weeds Thank you for the input. That's what I've been thinking. Considering the CRS is a localized one for NW Ohio, it seems like the "QGIS insertion point" is at the 0,0 of the CRS, just by eyeballing it. I was hoping there might be a way to clear the CRS from the vector lines in some way, but I don't believe so. I'll keep playing around with it, maybe I'll find a workaround. Redefining the insertion point isn't the worst thing in the world, but I was hoping to automate everything. Thanks!

Comment: In terms of automation I guess adding onto @Baswein's answer the process would be to assign the geometric centre/xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax of your features as the base point and feed the coordinates into the Affine Transform tool using data-defined override. If you string together Affine Transform and Save As dxf using Model Builder, that could get you close?

Answer (score 1):

As @she_weeds noted it seems that the insertion point created when creating the dxf is indeed the origin of the CRS that you are exporting as. My usual process when I have a CAD project that I know I am going to be going back and forth to GIS with is to start with the parcel layer from GIS and then align the rest of my CAD data to that. The benefit of that is that then when I want to move things back and forth they end up in the right spot as long as I use the same CRS.

Another option is to use the **Affine Transform** algorithm on the layer before exporting in it to CAD. Here is a potential work flow:

Create a point layer and add a point to be your consistent locus for your CAD project.

Then use the identify tool to find the **x** and **y** coordinates of your locus point.

Run the **Affine Transform** algorithm subtracting the **x** and **y** values of your locus point.
You could automate this step by using this expression in the x field substituting the layer ID from map layers in the expression dialog. And the same for the y except with y_min instead.  `- x_min( layer_property( 'Your Locus Layer layer ID','extent'))`

[image: Affine and identify windows]

Your resulting layer will now be down in Texas or in the middle of the ocean and GIS professionals will start sweating because it is in the wrong place on earth. However, when you export the resulting layer as a DXF the 0,0 point will be at the place in your geometry where your locus point was.

Another approach that is beyond my ken is to create a custom CRS for your project with the locus as your base point. The Geoscience plugin has a tool to do this however I was not able to get it to work.